# programatically change the initiator when inserting a new list item

Tags: sharepoint-online

is this possible to do?

I can creating new list items in C# using the client object model. We use a base account for all request and want to change the initiator to someone else when the list item is sent.

We can change the created by and modified by programatically but when there are work flows, the items show up as "Last modified at 8/29/2014 3:20 PM  by Workflow on behalf of logged in account"

I believe that this is the workflow initiator field but how do you change it?

Sharepoint 2013 online and having a web app on our intranet sending these requests. We use a master account to push the request so we are not using individual credentials for the user who is actually at the computer pushing the buttons.

Comment: did you tried it item["Created By"]= user;item.update(); ?

Comment: there is no created by field, there is 'app created by' and 'app modified by' both of which I have set to the user but the workflow initiator always shows up as the logged in account.

Comment: oh so maybe you mean to insert the item then get the item again and try to update it?

Comment: so I can programatically start a workflow but I still can't figure out how to make it change the user id of the person who started it.